# How do I make Files app show hidden files on iOS?

Tags: ios, files.app

I'm on iOS 15 and have some files with names that start with `.`, how do I view them in the Files app?

Comment: "Beside photos and videos, I don’t think that Apple allow any third-party apps to hide any files for security purpose." from [Henri Charles at Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-view-hidden-files-in-iPhone). This means that Apple is not expecting hidden files to be on iPhones in the first place thus they probably didn't implement a function to show these files.

Comment: @Wind_Explorer this question isn't about accessing the general filesystem of the device but items that are "hidden" in the UNIX sense (name prefixed by a dot). Files.app annoyingly prevents you from creating or seeing these files, despite there being no such restrictions for apps themselves. Fortunately there are ways around that, see my answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note: For the purposes of this response, "hidden" files and folders are items which have their name prefixed by a dot, i.e. `.myfile`, a common example is the `.ssh` folder (and "dotfiles" in general). Programs typically omit these files by default when listing the contents of a location. Items hidden in the sense of not being in a location accessible via the "Files" app (i.e. app internal storage, operating system files) are out of scope for this topic.

Furthermore, there is a distinction to be made between the *Files* app (`Files.app`) and the actual file locations, like "On this iPad"/"On this iPhone" and locations exposed by apps such as cloud storage providers. Apps can access the underlying location after being given permission via the folder picker.

The Files.app implements restrictions on handling hidden items; it is not possible to see or otherwise interact with them, and creating or renaming an item to begin with a dot yields an error that "[...] these names are reserved for the system"<sup>1</sup>.

However, this restriction is enforced by the Files.app "frontend", and not by some underlying mechanism, as such it is possible to use third party apps like *Textastic* and *a-Shell*, which can obtain "direct" access to a folder via the i(Pad)OS Folder picker, to see and modify these hidden items. As mentioned above, programs will usually omit hidden items by default, as such it may be necessary to explicitly show them, for instance by adding the [`-a` option](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls) to `ls` (`ls -a`) in *a-Shell*.

<sup>1</sup> One example for a hidden folder that is used by the system is `.Trash` in the root of "On this iPad"/"On this iPhone", which is the location where items from the aforementioned location are moved to when "deleted" using the Files.app. So *technically* speaking, you can access a hidden folder using Files.app, the "Recently Deleted"/".Trash" folder.

**Edit:** Rewrote comment. Removed part that called out other replies which were incorrect or not applicable.

Comment: Technically speaking, what you write here is correct however within the context of the question being asked, it’s out of scope.  The OP is asking about viewing hidden files in the  *Files* App.  It’s also not good form to call out other people in a post.

Comment: "what you write here is correct however within the context of the question being asked, it’s out of scope" - I would argue that most users see "On this iPad/iPhone" *as* the Files app, not a location that can be directly accessed by apps. Keep in mind that in 99% of cases where files are accessed, it is via the file picker which is essentially the Files app. | "It’s also not good form to call out other people in a post" - I might've done that in a comment if I was allowed to. Nonetheless I believe it is important to correct plainly false or not applicable information.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is short and bitter: **it's not possible**. On iOS and iPadOS you cannot see hidden files. Not in the Files app <strike>and not in any third party app</strike>.

As has been pointed out in the comments, hidden files can be accessible in other apps. But since the OP asked "How do I make Files app show hidden files", the answer is still: you can't.

Comment: Any way I could access hidden files in non-system directories?

Comment: I don’t think it matters where the files are. Apple won’t let you access them.

Comment: Also it depends on how far you want to go. Jailbreaking the iOS device allows you full access to the filesystem in many ways (VIA the Files.app? dunno...). **However** Jailbreaking is officially off topic here so if you want to pursue that avenue we can't help you.

Comment: @Christoph Only the Files.app "frontend" can't see or create these items, apps absolutely can. Please see my answer above.

Comment: @TeddyC Hidden items (i.e. items in otherwise accessible locations but prefixed by a dot) are accessible using third party apps that can request access to a folder and permit viewing these types of items. Off the top of my head I am aware of *Textastic* and *a-Shell*.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you can access hidden files in the Files app directly. However, you can transfer the folder containing the hidden files to another device (e.g. Mac) where you **can** access hidden files like this:

1. Tap and hold the folder containing hidden files in the iOS Files app and select **Compress** from the action menu
2. Send the resulting ZIP file to your Mac, e.g. via AirDrop
3. Unarchive the ZIP file on the Mac
4. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> in the Finder to show hidden files